# Language:C; Environment:Windows; Database: Azure Cloud

Tags: c, azure, connection-string, azure-sql-database

Can anyone provide me a sample code to test a connection string in C that is trying to to connect to Azure cloud DB.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/

there are lots of samples there